# Как повернуть экран ios на 90 градусов?

Tags: ios, objective-c, экран

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые коллеги!

У меня есть `ios`-приложение с двумя кнопками и одним заголовком. Что нужно добавить в код, чтобы приложение реагировало на событие поворота экрана - поворотом приложения на экране?

И опционально, где об этом можно почитать? (Ссылка на ютьюбный урок тоже будет очень кстати).

Comment: в info.plist посмотрите supported interface orientations, может там проблема

Comment: 4 items. 2 портрета, 2 пейзажа.

Comment: вот только хотел написать, что лок на вращение может быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема может заключаться в настройках самого ябло-устройства. Не исключено что на нём стоит, функция блокировки поворота экрана. Она выглядет как значок замка в верхней части экрана. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Чтобы её снять, нужно провести пальцами снизу вверх от низа экрана. Откроется окно. (Рисунок ниже). В этом окне можно снять блокировку.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В настройках проекта в XCode по вкладке General поставь галочки для нужных ориентаций.

Comment: поставил. не помогает. Точнее они уже стояли.

Comment: А у тебя Ui постоянный или с авторесайзами всякими?

Comment: ПО умолчанию. никаких ресайзов я не нашёл.

Comment: Тогда ставь констрейны или привязки к краям. Это в Билдере, в свойствах каждого элемента

Comment: Всё спасибо вам, плюсую. Но всё оказалось проще - у меня на айподе стоял блок поворота. Гыгы.